# how to change location of journalctl data?

Tags: systemd

I would like to change the place the systemd data is stored.

It seems like they are being written to /var/log/journal

I guess I could stop systemd-journald.service and then symlink the directory - but there must be a better "official" way. I see other people have asked kind of similar questions, but they are quite old. I'm sure there is now a way to change this, if not they need to program that.

Bit nervous I will brick the server, as it is in a DC.

Answer (score 1):

I just went for it.

```
systemctl stop systemd-journald.service
mv /var/log/journal /mnt/big12/
ln -s /mnt/big12/journal /var/log/journal
systemctl start systemd-journald.service
```

Only thing is, running processes stopped logging... once I restarted they logged again - so that is the only drawback AFAIK